# Best practice for Ninject to get different implementations based on top level project

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

I am just starting to learn Dependency Injection and I am stuck here.

My project has a WCF DataService over an Entity Framework DbContext.

```
public class MyDataService : DataService<MyDbContext>
{

    protected override MyDbContext CreateDataSource()
    {
        // I want to use dependency injection for this
        return new MyDbContext();
    }
}
```

The class is either
a) IIS hosted, so I don't have any control
b) for integration tests, created with `var host = new DataServiceHost(type, new Uri[] { });`

both use different contstructors for MyDbContext

So basically to inject the Context with this

```
    protected override MyDbContext CreateDataSource()
    {
        INinjectModule module = ???; // - 
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(module);
        return kernel.Get<MyDbContext>();
    }
```

So the question is, what is best practice in this situation?
Should I:

a) Create a Module in a Class Library that both main projects and the service use
b) Create a public static Variable inside the DataService project that holds the Ninject module.
c) Create a public static Variable inside the DataService project that holds the Ninject kernel
d) Something else.

I would prefer something like

```
    protected override MyDbContext CreateDataSource()
    {
        DefaultKernel.Get<MyDbContext>();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you should have a *Composition Root*. That is, a single place where your `Kernel` is created (not in every single function).

Secondly, you don't need a `NinjectModule` here.. you're asking Ninject to create an instance of a concrete object (which in almost all circumstances.. defeats the purpose).

What you should create, is a separate `NinjectModule` pass it into the constructor of the `Kernel`.. something like this:

```
interface IContext {
}

class MyDbContext : DbContext, IContext {
}

class YourModule : NinjectModule {
    protected override void Bind() {
        Bind<IContext>().To<MyDbContext>();
    }
}

// In your composition root somewhere
var kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectModule[] { new YourModule() });

// in your createdatasource method
kernel.Get<IContext>();
```

This will get you started. Normally, your composition root is what drives injection of objects throughout your application, thereby eliminating the need to pass the `Kernel` around (which you will have to do in your current setup).

The hard thing to understand when starting out with DI/IoC is that it is the container's job to create your entire dependency graph. Therefore, if you setup the following bindings:

```
IContract1 -> ConcreteObject1
IContract2 -> ConcreteObject2
IContract3 -> ConcreteObject3
```

..and have the following setup:

```
class ConcreteObject1 : IContract1 {
    public ConcreteObject1(IContract2 contract3) {
    }
}

class ConcreteObject2 : IContract2 {
    public ConcreteObject2(IContract3 contract3) {
    }
}
```

If you ask your container for a concrete implementation of `IContract1` (which will be `ConcreteObject1`), then it will create it.... BUT: `ConcreteObject1` requires a concrete implementation of `IContract2` in the constructor. So the container says "Wait, I know how to create this".. and passes in an instance of `ConcreteObject2`. Again, it says "wait, `ConcreteObject2` wants a concrete implementation of `IContract3`.. again, it goes and fetches one.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks, there is one thing I don't get: Should the `Composition Root` be inside the main project or inside a class library that every other project references?

Comment: Generally they are "Top-Down". For a web app, put it in the web app Global.asax.cs. For WinForms, Program.cs.

Comment: I have updated my answer to help understand a bit better how the Kernel only needs to be in your composition root.

Comment: thanks for your effort. The Top-Down approach is what I want to achive. But how do pass the kenel down the dependecy graph?

Another situation: I use NLog for logging. In my main app I configure NLog. every other project uses the static `LogManager.GetLogger(...)` method to obtain a logger. Do I have to implement something similar myself? Or is there something predefined (just an example: `Ninject.KernelManager.GetDefaultKernel`) If that is not the case, I have to create my own class library and use this in other projects.

Comment: You don't pass the `Kernel` around. The kernel's job is to really only request the top level objects. When it creates a top level object, it creates any dependencies required all the way down. So basically, you're passing a dependency with a dependency with a dependency all the way down.. and the kernel knows how to create those objects for you (without passing it down). It's hard to explain without writing up an entire tutorial on the subject :/